# My spinner adapter is not updating the spinner values on calling notifyDataSetUpdate change

Tags: android, spinner

This is my spinner function that initializing the spinner and setting adapter data  is called in OnCreate() of the Activity

```
  private void spinnerSetting() {
    DataBaseOperations dataBaseOperations = new DataBaseOperations(this);
    spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.volt_spinner_);

    categories = dataBaseOperations.getInvertersType();
    // Creating adapter for spinner
     dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, categories);

    // Drop down layout style - list view with radio writeNfcBt
    dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    // attaching data adapter to spinner
    spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            mkvValue = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });
}
```

From this piece of code when i click the button it update the my List(categories) which provides data to spinner adapter then i call notifyDataSetChange() but it didn't the spinner values but my List(categories ) are updated and have new values but spinner is showing old values

```
List<Inverters> allData = inverter.getData();
DataBaseOperations dataBaseOperations = new DataBaseOperations(AdminPanelActivity.this);
dataBaseOperations.addInvertersNames(allData);
categories.clear();
//dataAdapter.clear();
categories = dataBaseOperations.getInvertersType();
dataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Adapter holds the reference to the list passed in its constructor.

```
categories = dataBaseOperations.getInvertersType();
dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, categories);
```

`dataBaseOperations.getInvertersType()` is creating a new `ArrayList` each time it is called, but the Adapter doest not change its internal reference.
That's why you don't see changes after calling  `categories = dataBaseOperations.getInvertersType()`, it is a new list that the adapter doesn't know about.

---

You should do instead:

```
List<Inverters> allData = inverter.getData();
DataBaseOperations dataBaseOperations = new DataBaseOperations(AdminPanelActivity.this);
dataBaseOperations.addInvertersNames(allData);
categories.clear();
categories.addAll(dataBaseOperations.getInvertersType());
dataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: it's not working , not updating the spinner  , it's only when i intialize the adapter again with new data

Comment: but i want to know why notifyDataSetChange() is not working

Comment: Because you are creating a new reference. You can also do `dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, categories); spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);` when you are trying to update data